# Get followers count without api From Instagram

Tags: php, api, instagram

I had code that show my followers count on the pages, but i think this week instagram updated the website,no more is showing followers count in profile when using curl

Here is my code that worked before:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/example';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); // Removed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Added
$data = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/<meta content="([0-9]+).*Followers/',$data,$result);
echo $result[1];
```

Here is the view-source why is missing followers counter:

http://pasted.co/ad3dc7d2

I can't post the view-score here because here is limit  30.000 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/example';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/ot.html)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); // Removed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Added
$data = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/"edge_followed_by"\:\{"cunt":(.*?)\}/',$data,$result);
echo $result[1];
```

I changed regex pattern. It will work.

Comment: it is showing blank

Comment: I just tried again and it's worked. I think no problem in the code. Are you sure whether curl is working correctly?

Comment: I checked now is working others website , i want to ask what verson of php are you using?

Comment: I'm using 7.1.x version currently. But it should have worked for another versions as well. What's your PHP version?

Comment: I'm using version of php 5.6

Comment: i think it should work , cuz is is working with others website ,  i double checked if is code is written right, but i don't know now what is the problem

Comment: I just tried on PHP 5.6.x and it still worked as well. Maybe, problem is related with your configurations but i'm not sure.

Comment: here is the view-source: http://pasted.co/ad3dc7d2

Comment: to the server is missing followers counter,but when i use view-source i can see the followers counter

Comment: Instagram started hardly limiting all ips which are owned by any server/vps/web hosting providers if you are trying to scraping them without api. Best is to try residential proxy.

Comment: Yea it is true i switch to another hosting it works fine  @Juri